# Why do the Marleyans turn Eldians into titans when exiling?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So I understand they're really racist, but when exiling, why not just throw people off into the desert?  Why make them titans too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used to turn eldians into pure titans and release them in the island to serve as both punishment and to ENSURE no eldian would leave the island.